# ssh with kerberos: .k5login for all users in particular domain

Tags: authentication, dns, kerberos, openssh

I am trying to let every users from particular domain ssh into client. For now I am using .k5login file at home directory with users listed. However, this is cumbersome with more users joining to the system. Therefore is there anyway I can let every users from particular domain ssh into client.
Example:  *@EXAMPLE.LOCAL
inside .k5login which would allow users like
user1@EXAMPLE.LOCAL as well as user2@EXAMPLE.LOCAL to ssh into client.

I have also tried to using /etc/krb5.conf

```
[realms]
 EXTENSODATA.LOCAL = { 
  auth_to_local = RULE:[1:$1@$0](.*@EXAMPLE\.LOCAL)s/(\d+)@.*/root/
```

which should have let any users from EXAMPLE.LOCAL resolve to root?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my dilemma by editing /etc/krb5.conf

```
[libdefaults]
k5login_authoritative = false
```

Which will use other means of authentication if the user is not found inside .k5login.